# Best way to ensure a Model attribute is consistently downcased and stripped?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation

I'd like to know what the best way to ensure a user supplied parameter is downcased and stripped in all situations.

I would like to achieve the following:

1. Guarantee that the attribute will not be saved to the DB unless stripped/downcased
2. Queries against the db should always downcase/strip the attribute
3. Validations are run against a downcased/stripped version of user supplied params
4. Models return downcase/stripped attribute (which shouldn't be a problem given item #1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to write a `before_save` callback method, within which you downcase and strip the attributes set by the user.

For eg:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :format_values

  def format_values
    self.name = self.name.downcase
  end
end
```

**EDIT**

I had missed your 3rd point about validations. So if you need to also run validations on these values. You'd need to use the `before_validation` callback instead.

Answer (score 0):

You would do that in a `before_validation` callback:

```
# in your model
before_validation :normalize_attribute

private
def normalize_attribute
  # change `attribute` to your actual attribute's name
  self.attribute = attribute.strip.downcase if attribute
end
```

Or you could do that with a custom setter:

```
# change `attribute` to your actual attribute's name
def attribute=(value)
  write_attribute(:attribute, value.strip.downcase) if value
end
```

The first option will sanitize the attribute's value every time the object is saved, even if the value has not changed. This might be helpful if you introduce this sanitize method when records in the database already exist, because this allow to sanitize all existing record with just one line of code in the Rails console: `Model.find_each(&:save)`. The second option will only sanitize values when they are set. This is a bit more performant.

I both cases I suggest to check for `if attribute` otherwise you might call `strip.downcase` on `nil` values what would lead to an exception.

Comment: If you don't mind, would you please update your answer to include when you choose one option over the other?

Comment: @BillyBlobSnortin: Done

Answer (score 0):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_validation :format_values

  def format_values
    self.name = self.name.strip.downcase if name
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated the answer based on the comment.

No need to get fancy with callbacks (don't use callbacks, anyway). Just override the setter for your attribute.

```
class MyModel
  def some_attribute=(value)
    value = value.strip.downcase if value
    write_attribute(:some_attribute, value)
  end
end
```

Comment: Wouldn't this allow a non-downcased/non-stripped value to be persisted?